# Getting "login" error when trying to login using facebook provider in Quickblox

Tags: android, quickblox, quickblox-android

I'm developing an Android app that uses de QUickblox Android SDK and I'm getting this error when trying to login using the facebook provider by calling the `QBUsers.signInUsingSocialProvider()` method.

**login":["should contain alphanumeric and punctuation characters only"]**

The user which I'm trying to login is already registered at **Users** section with a **facebook id**, **email**, **full name**, **password** and **login** (**regmoraes**, which matches the criteria).  I started to get this error after updating the quickblox android sdk from 2.4 to 2.5.1 . How can I solve it? Change the quickblox sdk back to 2.4 is off topic :)

Comment: Hi there, can you post your logs of a request

Comment: Hi @IgorKhomenko, I solved the issue by removing and adding the user again, therefore I can't reproduce the error again